# Solving for $x$ in $a^2\left(x-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\right)\left(\pi-\arcsin\frac{x}{a}\right)=3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\left(3x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-x^2+a^2-b^2\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Our crazy teacher gave this to us to solve!

$$a^2\left(x-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\right)\left(\pi-\arcsin\frac{x}{a}\right)=3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\left(3x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}-x^2+a^2-b^2\right)$$

Comment: Solve over what? Why should you expect a closed form for the solution for $x$ over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I am not expecting you or others to find x numerically. just like ax+b=c that x is (c-b)/a

Comment: If you substitute $x = a\sin \theta$, divide through by $a^3$, and let $c = \sqrt{1 - (b/a)^2}$, then you get the equation $$(\sin \theta - c)(\pi - \theta) = 3\cos \theta(3c\sin\theta - \sin^2\theta + c^2)$$ which might be a bit easier to comptemplate, where $0 \le c \le 1$ and $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$.

Comment: This doesn't appear like it's going to be difficult -- it's only messy. If you're like Euler, you'll just plunge into the expansions and simplifications. You'll eventually get an equation involving a sine and at worst a quadratic in $x.$ That may not have a finite closed form, but it's not *that* difficult -- just involves a lot of tedious, unmotivated algebraic manipulations. If I were you I'd plunge this into a CAS software.